# Truncated Normal Distribution: Example of Integrate by Parts

Tags: probability, integration

In Vershynin's [book](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#) High Dimensional Probability, there is an easy exercise I am doing for self-study:

Let $g \sim N(0,1)$. Show that for all $t\geq 1$, we have

$$\mathbb E g^2 \mathbb 1_{\{g>t\}} = t \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2} + \mathbb P \{g > t\}.$$

The left hand side is the integral

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_t^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2/2}dx$$

So, I integrate by parts:

$$ u= x^2 \qquad du = 2x dx$$
$$ v= \frac{e^{-x\frac{x^2}{2}}}{-x} \qquad dv =e^{-x^2/2}dx$$

\begin{align*} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_t^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2/2}dx 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int u dv \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \left( uv - \int v du  \right) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \left(te^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}+ 2\int_t^\infty e^{-x^2/2} dx\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  te^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}+2 \mathbb P\{ g>t\}
\end{align*}

I can't figure out how to get rid of the 2 in that second term. Is the book mistaken? Or did I make some stupid error somewhere?

Comment: Let $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Denoting the standard normal pdf by $\phi(\cdot)$ and using the fact that $\phi'(t)=-t\phi(t)$,

$$\displaystyle E(X^2\mathbf1_{X>t})=\int_t^\infty x\cdot x\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\qquad\qquad\quad\displaystyle=x\int_t^\infty x\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_t^\infty\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\qquad\qquad\quad\displaystyle=-\lim_{A\to\infty} x\phi(x)|_t^A+P(X>t)$$

$$\qquad\qquad\quad\displaystyle=t\phi(t)+P(X>t)$$.

Comment: In terms of integrals, the claim in the text is true, as discussed in @StubbornAtom's Comment. Also for $t=2,$ numerical integration gives 0.13073, which agrees with the stated answer. However, this is _not_ a 'truncated normal' in the usual use of that terminology. For example: such a truncated normal distribution would have a density function that integrates to unity over $(2, \infty)$ and a random variable $X$ with that distribution would have $E(X^2) \approx 5.73.$

Comment: @StubbornAtom this definitely works, thank you! Just wondering, did you see a mistake in my reasoning? Clearly I did not set up the Integration by Parts correctly, but I though I did it right. How could we get two different answers?

Comment: If cannot spot your error then it is better to do the integration carefully from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better choice for u and v.  $u=x,\ dv=xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx, \ v=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.  Integral is the expression you are looking for.